# using pytest to test Controller.py (python 3.8)

Tags: python, unit-testing, lambda, pytest, python-3.8

I have to write a  Controller test case of a lambda function using python3.8.

it is a sign_up function, it will do 3 if-else validation to decide whether to call 3 different APIs or not.

```
async def sign_up(request: ProxyRequest):
    
    api_requests = []
    #some validation....
    if condition1:
        api_requests.append(service.$method1(seesion,request))
    if condition2:
        api_requests.append(service.$method2(seesion,request))
    if condition3:
        api_requests.append(service.$method3(seesion,request))
    
    
    try:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(config) as session:
            #for loop to call the api of the api_requests....
    except Exception as e:
        session.close()
        raise e
    
    return response({#some json...})
```

May I ask How can I mock the response of those 3 api_requests whether than really calling those API?

this is the code in my test case

```
@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_sign_up_successful(mocker):
    mockEvent = {
        #headers, body.... of the request
    }
    
    
    mocker.patch('path to the api_requests method1 in service', return_value = {'statusCode': '200'})
    mocker.patch('path to the api_requests method2 in service', return_value = {'statusCode': '200'})
    mocker.patch('path to the api_requests method3 in service', return_value = {'statusCode': '200'})

    mockRequest = ProxyRequest(mockEvent)
    response = await sign_up(mockRequest)
    
    expectedMessage = 'success'
    assert response['statusCode'] == 200
    assert json.loads(response['body'])['message'] == expectedMessage
```

The result of the pytest is said that the 'statusCode' of the test is 500 !=200 (because some reason the **real API** is currently response status 500)

This is because the test calls the real API of the real method rather than the fake method I mocked,

How can I make the sign_up test call the method I mocked??